# Multiple Random quote generator without repetation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, quotes

Hey I have been written a code on to Random Quote generator

```
const qouteBtn = document.querySelector('.random');
const quoteView = document.querySelector('#randomQuote');
const quote = [
  { quote: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken' },
  { quote: 'So Many Books, So Little Time' },
  { quote: "Strangers think I'm Quiet. My Friends think I'm outgoing. My best friends know that I'm Completely Insane" },
  { status: 'A room without books is like a body without soul' },
  { status: 'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough' },
];
quoteBtn.addEventListener('click', randomQuote);
function randomQuote() {
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);

  quoteView.innerHTML = quote[i].quote;
}
```

I have made a button so that as I click the quote would changed . But how can I make it as when I click a button it would creat a

and insert quote on it and again if I click it would creat another

and insert on it without repetation. SO that if I click on the button

```
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

The p element would create itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make a large div (as a container for everything) and then

```
largeDiv.innerHTML += '<div class="innerDiv">' + quote[i].quote + '</div>';
```

Then add the style for the .innerDiv. This will add additional div to the previous ones.